# /proc consuming space on hard disk gradually

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage, disk, amazon-ec2

EC2 instance running centos 7.0 hard disk space is consumed slowly, which is flushed after reboot.

Content : Base OS, Cloudwatch Agent, CodeDeploy agent, nginx, Anti Virus MacFee, Java application (log file is under control).

**Screen shot 1 before reboot** : Disk space utilized **75%**

As per this screenshot we are finding top 10 most space consuming files and /proc is on top.

[image]

**Screen shot 2 After reboot** : Disk space utilized **9%**

used files are flushed, not able to identify if the issue is caused by application or other components.

[image]

Comment: `/proc` doesn't live on disk, it's merely a representation of processes currently running.  Unsure what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: *"we are finding top 10 most space consuming files and /proc is on top"*  No it is not, and this could hardly be the case, since `/proc` is not even a real filesystem.  It seems you barely looked at the output of the command you ran -- do you read where it says `du: cannot access ./proc ...` ?

Comment: There's not really any question in here, and as several folks have pointed out, you badly misinterpreted the output. But if you want to know what uses your disk space and what to do about it, I suggest you use something like `du -x --max-depth=1 /` before and after a boot, and then before the next boot use a similar command in the directories that shrink the most - if it isn't painfully obvious what uses the space.

Comment: do you really care what the largest file is?  or are you trying to find what's using up all the space?  if the latter, then start by running `du -sch` against all real-filesystem directories in `/` (e.g. with something like `find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -fstype ext4 -o -fstype xfs \) -exec du -sch {} + | sort -h`.  That will give you the top level directories sorted by size.  then do the same for each of the largest directories (e.g. /var, /opt) to find which of their subdirectories use the most space. and keep drilling down until you find the culprit.

Comment: Most likely something is creating a huge log file (or files) somewhere under /tmp, /var, or /opt....log file(s) which just keeps on growing until the system is rebooted.  that's a bug.  or poor sysadmin practices - such logs should be rotated, compressed, and/or expired (deleted) regularly.   Note that just deleting a log file may not release the space - the program(s) which have open file handles to the log file(s) need to be made to close and then re-open them after they are rotated and/or deleted.

Answer (score 8):

You’re misreading the output: the lines about `/proc` are error messages because `du` can’t read some of the files `find` is asking it to use; they don’t indicate that files in `/proc` are among the top-ten biggest files on your system. In any case, as [steve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104877/steve) mentioned, `/proc` is its own, virtual, file system, and doesn’t occupy any space on your drive.

To avoid listing irrelevant files, you can tell `find` not to cross file system boundaries using the `-xdev` option.

The files which appear to be giving you trouble are `/var/log/awslogs.log` and `/var/log/awslogs.1`: your first command lists them as the two biggest files on your system, and they don’t appear in the output of your second command (or rather, they’re smaller — I see `awslogs.log.1` further down the list).

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you pipeline stdout and don't suppress stderr.

Because `sort` needs to have the entire input buffer before it can do its job (obviously) it doesn't actually start passing output on to `head` before `find` is finished searching.

However, since you left stderr unsuppressed, `du` reports errors as to files that stopped existing between the time `find` saw them and `du` was started, and these error messages get reported the moment they're raised (because stderr isn't being buffered).

If you run the find command without the sort and head pipeline you'll see what's happening.